# pound not proxying request

Tags: linux, proxy, virtualbox, pound

I configured pound like this:

```
ListenHTTP
        Address 192.168.21.10
        Port    1632
        Service
                BackEnd
                        Address 192.168.22.220
                        Port    1622
                End
                BackEnd
                        Address 192.168.22.220
                        Port    1612
                End
        End
End

ListenHTTP
        Address 192.168.21.10
        Port    1634
        Service
                BackEnd
                        Address 192.168.22.220
                        Port    1534
                End
                BackEnd
                        Address 192.168.22.220
                        Port    1644
                End
        End
End
```

I do see with tcpflow it is getting requests on192.168.21.10 on port 1632 but its not forwarding to my server which i have listening on 192.168.22.220 (and not forwarding the requests (not proxying) to any other server...

its my first time using pound i know its up by its service, i don't see any log messages on var/log/messages

can anyone help me please?
thanks

Comment: So the obvious question, the proxyer and the proxyee are on different subnets, the separate subnets are routed correctly I assume?

Comment: thanks for comment i guess its probably something around this issue i was using virtualbox

Comment: Ahh, Virtual machines too. If you are using NAT, then you will really be stuck. Make sure the machines have their network stack set to "Bridged".

Comment: Can you even ping between hosts? From the proxy server can you telnet to the backend server on the desire port?

Comment: See here for details on Pound logging: http://a-n-t-h-o-r.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/working-with-pound-and-logging.html